# how to return Observables from firebase firebase function

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have running my application perfectly with

> "@angular/fire": "^6.1.5",
> "firebase": "^8.6.3",

and it was like

Service.ts

```
getUserEventSummary(userId) {
this.firestore.collection(`/user/${userId}/event_summary`).doc('current').snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes => changes.payload.data())
    );
}
```

Component.ts

```
this.service.getUserEventSummary(this.userId).subscribe((res: any) => {
    this.values = res;
}
```

And such code is all over the application.
Now I have moved to the latest version of firebase that is

> "firebase": "^9.0.1",
> "@angular/fire": "^7.0.4",

And new changes are

service.ts

```
getUserEventSummary(userId) {
 return getDoc(doc(db, `user/${userId}/event_summary`, 'current'));
}
```

And component.ts

```
this.service.getUserEventSummary(this.userId).subscribe((docSnap: any) => {
   if (docSnap.exists()) {
        this.values = docSnap.data();;
    }
 }
```

I need a method that returns the same behavior i.e. observables that this code returning promise.

Moreover, snapshot changes are hard to implement on the service files.
Please help me with a better approach than changing the code of components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you filter and map inside the service method, then you should be able to leave the component code untouched. You should go for something like this in your service:

```
import { /* ... */, from } from 'rxjs';

getUserEventSummary(userId) {
  return from(getDoc(doc(db, `user/${userId}/event_summary`, 'current'))).pipe(
    filter((docSnap) => docSnap.exists()),
    map(docSnap => docSnap.data())
  );
}
```

You can use `from` to create an observable from that `Promise` object.

Comment: Yes I tried this already but
Getting Errors, Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Promise<DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>>'

Comment: @cakePHP Can you please check my updated answer? I included a conversion of the Promise to Observable.

Comment: Could you please define method for `snapshotChanges` too as that is not working with this way

Comment: Can you check [the documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md) and let me know what is still not clear?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68949123/verify-my-domain-with-apple-in-a-ionic-capacitor-pwa. Please help me on this